# Why weren’t skyscrapers affected by the magnet in Transformers: Age of Extinction?

Tags: transformers, transformers-age-of-extinction, transformers-live-action-series

When the "big magnet" hovers over the modern skyscrapers, why didn't they get sucked up, just like cars, boats, Autobots and parts of a stadium would?

Skyscrapers are made of steel and steel is magnetic. So why didn't they get torn apart by the magnet?

Comment: i'd have to rewatch, but i recall loose bits from higher parts of buildings being pulled up, just not the entire buildings themselves

Comment: Because the film was a 2hr45 advert for plastic toys, made by a man-child with a bizarre fetish for explosives.

Comment: In X Men: Apocalypse, Magneto had used the same magnetism to destroy everything and guess what? It can destroy skyscrapers!

Comment: The way the big magnet works and the way Magneto works is fundamentally different. The big magnet just pulls - in theory, that means only pieces of ferrous metals not adequately secured against the degree of magnetic force exerted will be attracted to it. Not so with Magneto: he can sense the natural magnetic fields in the Earth and manipulate them. With Apocalypse's augmentation, this ability extends planetwide. You are comparing pulling with magnets vs manipulating magnetic atoms here. Magneto could rip the Earth's core out if he so willed it.

Answer (score 2):

Skyscrapers are secured directly to the bedrock beneath them and rather heavy so a straight up lift of the entire building would need a huge magnetic field.

Comment: But the big magnet can still rip the building in half or in big chunks, without affecting the bottom. Have you've watched X Men Apocalypse?

Comment: @STARWARSFAN, you know that X Men Apocalypse was just a movie? :)